# UIView: opaque vs. alpha vs. opacity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

How do `opaque` `alpha` and the opacity of the background work together for a UIView and what are the differences between them?

[UIView http://i.minus.com/jb2IP8TXbYTxKr.png](http://i.minus.com/jb2IP8TXbYTxKr.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079160/how-to-correctly-set-alpha-of-uiview-ios/17079360#17079360

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`opaque` means don't draw *anything* underneath, even if you are transparent.

The background color's alpha only affects the background color's transparency, not anything else drawn on the view.

`alpha` affects everything drawn on the view.

---

The opaque property can give you a speed increase - if you know that your view will *never* have transparency you can set this to `YES` and when iOS renders your view it can make some performance optimisations and render it faster. If this is set to `NO` iOS will have to blend your view with the view underneath, even if it doesn't happen to contain any transparency.

The alpha will also affect the alpha of the backround color i.e. if the background color is 0.5 transparent and the alpha is also 0.5, this has the effect of making the background view's alpha 0.25 (0.5 * 0.5).

Comment: I think you mean background color's alpha is 0.25, not background view's. I suppose background view and background color are two different things.

Comment: I mean the alpha component of the `backgroundColor` property of the `UIView` we are talking about :) I've not talked about nested views at all!

Comment: This is set to YES by default.


@property(nonatomic,getter=isOpaque) BOOL              opaque;                     // default is YES. ...

Answer (score 13):

To the very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8520656/1656515) by deanWombourne it's worth to add that, unless you don't draw your own content using the drawRect: method, the opaque property has no effect.

[Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622622-opaque):

> You only need to set a value for the opaque property in subclasses of
>   UIView that ***draw their own content*** using the drawRect: method. The
>   opaque property ***has no effect in system-provided classes*** such as
>   UIButton, UILabel, UITableViewCell, and so on.

If you draw your own content, keep in mind, that opaque is just a hint

> This property provides a ***hint to the drawing system*** as to how it
>   should treat the view.

and some more guidelines from the same Apple's doc:

> If the view is opaque and either does not fill its bounds or contains
>   wholly or partially transparent content, the results are
>   unpredictable. You should always set the value of this property to NO
>   if the view is fully or partially transparent.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS alpha vs opacity vs opaque**

[[Color Blended Layers]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681213/4770877)

`CALayer.opacity` is a source for `UIView.alpha`- [0.0 - 1.0] - apply `alpha` to all view(subviews, sublayers). It's like make a single flat bitmap image based on all content and apply alpha. That is why if view contains another subview or sublayer - **no** `Blended Layers` and **is** `Off-screen Rendered` is applied

`CALayer.backgroundColor` is a source for `UIView.backgroundColor` - applies color only on background(not subviews, sublayers)

`CALayer.opaque` is a source for `UIView.opaque` - Boolean property which hint's framework about some optimizations. But on practice it is [not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10444422/4770877)

Experiments

input

[image] 
[image]

`alpha`

```
view1.alpha = 0.5
//or
view1.layer.opacity = 0.5
```

result and `Off-screen Rendered`

[image]
[image]

`backgroundColor`

```
view1.backgroundColor = .cyan.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
//or
view1.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
```

result and `Blended Layers`

[image]
[image]