# How to correctly set alpha of UIView? [iOS]

Tags: ios, uiview, alpha

I have `UIView` with lots of subviews (UILabel, UITextView, etc.).

If a set alpha 0.6 to main view all the subviews takes this alpha.

How to set alpha separately of main view?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 [view setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];

 //try this.. dont try to set alpha of UIView and also your subviews will not affect
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES
```

This will make it use `group opacity` and everything should composite as you'd expect.