# iOS Modal Popup Starts Transparent But Turns Blank

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios-simulator

Using the iOS Simulator, I'm trying to get the modal to appear over the parent controller with a transparent background.  I define the controller as:

```
var controller = new DailyRewardController();

controller.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext;
controller.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
controller.View.Opaque = true;

PresentViewController (controller, true, null);
```

The controller initially appears with a transparent background, but as the animation finishes, the screen is now black, as in the following screenshot.  Note: ignore the hideous popup; it's only a prototype :-)

[image]

This is how it appears after the animation finishes; however, as the animation runs, it's transparent...  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

After finish the animation of presentviewcontroller the root view controller disappears, thats the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code,

```
var popupVC = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("PopupViewController");
popupVC.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext;
NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(popupVC, false);
```

Comment: Could you explain the below code? A nice explaination is the best if you want OP to understand and if you want upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
controller.View.Opaque = true;
```

You are setting the background color to "Clear" but then turning Opaque to true which is contradictory.

See here:
[UIView: opaque vs. alpha vs. opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520434/uiview-opaque-vs-alpha-vs-opacity)