# Is Core Animation color blended layers useful or say is it necessary?

Tags: ios, core-animation, instruments

**Color Blended Layers**
Open Instruments and choose the Core Animation template located under iOS / Graphics. First, click in the Core Animation instrument's timeline to reveal the bottom pane and find the section labeled "Debug Options". Check the "Color Blended Layers" box, which will show a red overlay over layers that were blended and a green overlay over layers drawn without blending.

**Is Core Animation color blended layers useful or say is it necessary?** 
I found that the system UI is red blended yet. 
And my app is also red blended in some areas.

what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, It's necessary to fix the blended layers, 
For example: you background have a white color and you add a label in the view .and set background color clear color. This will make your layer blended.
But this is unnecessary to calculate .
If you set your label color same as your view. 
scrolling performance will improve a lot.
You can feel it.

Comment: If your view is not to scroll, you have blended layer,maybe it's OK.

Comment: I know this ,If my view don't need scroll . And if it has blended layer, is it necessary to fix?

Comment: It's no necessary, since it just run once, the performance is not improved obviously.

Comment: The `Label` has an extra sublayer when it's displaying Chinese. We have to use `clipsToBounds = true` to fix the color blend layers. But the `clipsToBounds` is another effort to the system. Is it still worth to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Via [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice.html):

> **Color Blended Layers**. Shows blended view layers. Multiple view layers that are drawn on top of each other with blending enabled are highlighted in red. Reducing the amount of red in your app when this option is selected ***can dramatically improve your apps performance***. Blended view layers are often the cause for slow table scrolling.

It's all about the performance of your UI rendering, if you will work with opaque option (or property) and all your layers will be green, your rendering will be super fast.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Red color in `Color Blended Layers` says that you should take additional look at this view and if possible optimise a layer to minimize effort to calculate result view

[[iOS debug rendering]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681213/4770877)