# Improve performance for `UITableViewCell` with non-uniform content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uistackview

I have a `UITableView` whose cells contain dynamic content.

Let's say there could be three types of cell contents (in reality, there are many more).

`Type1`: 3 `UILabel`stacked on top of each other

`Type2`: 2 `UIButtons` stacked next to each other

`Type3`: 1 `UISlider` I the center

I have classes for these UI elements.

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I add these to the `contentView`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID)!
  cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() } // Remove everything before adding new stuff       
  cell.contentView.addSubview(Type3())  // Pretend there's logic here to decide whether to use Type1, Type2, or Type3
  return cell
}
```

This works for now, but clearly is very hacky and not elegant. How can I go about this?

Comment: Why not just create 3 subclasses of `UITableViewCell` for each of the content types?

Comment: @7ball You can create different tableviewCell instead of only different contentView that may consume less memory as compared this runtime binding.
or you may use https://texturegroup.org/ for better performance.

Comment: mag_zbc is right, if you want high performance in tableView you should be taking full advantage of reusable cells, removing all subviews and adding a whole new view hierarchy means alot of drawing and no reuse at all, it would quite likely cause you all sorts of issues and i doubt it would ever reach 60FPS for smooth scrolling

Comment: Also you can use UIStackViews for easy hiding/unhiding of child views, but the first option using 3 different subclasses is more applicable. Also try to kill color blended layers for better scrolling performance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008109/is-core-animation-color-blended-layers-useful-or-say-is-it-necessary